# Comparing two files and displaying which line is different

Tags: c#

I currently have a project that has 6 files read into the program and when given an user input it will display whether the two files are the same or different. However, I would like to build a system that not only tells me if these files are different, but also at which lines they're different. Hopefully someone has tried creating something similar?

```
class FileCompare : UserInput
    {
        static string InputFileA;
        static string InputFileB;

        public static void RepoCompare()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File 1: File 1A.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("File 2: File 1B.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("File 3: File 2A.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("File 4: File 2B.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("File 5: File 3A.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("File 6: File 3B.txt");

            string Ans = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" Which files would you like to compare? (Please make this the exact pathway!): ");
                Ans = Console.ReadLine();
                if (i == 0)
                    InputFileA = getData(Ans);
                else if (i == 1)
                    InputFileB = getData(Ans);
            }

            if (InputFileA == InputFileB)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"File A and File B are the same");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"File A and File B are different \n Difference on Line: ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
```

The code above shows how when given user input it will then compare the two files.

Comment: Never seen anything that compare files... What a novel idea... Just use `fc` on Windows or any one of probably millions of tools that compare files. Even Visual Studio/VS Code have it... As result - please clarify what kind of problem you are facing to implement it yourself? [edit] question with what you tried to do so and how it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: @TSTB You meant comparing 2 files line by line? It's very easy by using loop. But in fact, even the file has been inserted one line somewhere, then it makes all lines from that inserted to the end would be difference. I suggest you test with [git diff technology](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch)

Comment: You need to clarify how advanced you want the comparison to be. As @TấnNguyên mentioned then you can go full git diff, or you could simply just compare the files line by line, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: My task was to implement the following: To implement a simple C# console version of the git diff command and I need to include the following things: 

Display whether the files are different (Which I've managed to do thus far)
Display where the files are different i.e which line.

Comment: Use GitHub ...!

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the comment that there are tools like that already.

Still, lets think of it as a useful exercise on its own rather than a practical tool.

First, what you mean by the same. Is it that line 1 in file A and line 1 in file 2 has to be the same? Easy enough - read both files line by line and compare each line. Done.

But is that really what you want? What if the files are:

```
File A

1: A
2: B
3: C
```

and

```
File B

1: 
2: A
3: B
4: C
```

What's now? Using previous method they are different on every line! But are they really? So here you need to take a context into account. Take a line from a first file. Search for it in the second file. Make sure that starting from there you have similar lines following the matching pair. If not matching. Repeat the process with the first non-matching line - maybe it's somewhere further in the second file.

Since we are considering that an exercise I'll leave the implementation details to the author of the question.

Comment: Okay so File 1A and 1B contain the exact same data and the files are the same size so when the program is run and compares those two files it will output: "File A and File B are the same" however File 1A and File 2A contain different sets of data (I'm essentially trying to create a git diff command but in C#).

Comment: You do include the context. So if you have a scenario like my example it will show you that the first line has been added to File B but that otherwise they are the same. You need to take a non-empty line and search for it. In the example you would find the File A line 1 is in File B line 2. From there you compare A:2 with B:3, A:3 with B:4, and so on, and keep marking them as similar. Then once you run into a line that's different you repeat that - assumption here is there may be an extra insert there. Of course it's only an outline.

Comment: The task is not trivial at all. The git diff for instance is quite complex and takes care of a lot of edge cases. Check the documentation of the git diff for a better understanding of what you need to do: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c

Comment: My task was to implement the following: To implement a simple C# console version of the git diff command and I need to include the following things: Display whether the files are different (Which I've managed to do thus far) Display where the files are different i.e which line.

Comment: If you need a naive version then just going line by line and displaying that will achieve your goal though I'd say there won't be much utility in a tool like this.

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? (I apologise I'm new to C#)

Comment: Do that on both files at the same time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: This isn't an answer, you ask more questions than you provide answers for.